# What are the conditions needed to add an attribute/s ( foreign keys + this attribute/s ) to a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, relational-database

For example:
I have 2 tables X and Y which have a many-to-many relationship Z in between.
Table Z have the ID's of the 2 tables as a foreign keys plus an attribute like (rating). Everyone of X can rate everyone of Y for just 1 time.
So can i add this attribute to the Relationship or not?

Comment: You always *can*. But whether you *should* depends on details you haven't given about what set of rows can be in X, Y & Z at one time. You say {x, y} subrows are unique in Z. Presumably they will be in the new version of Z? What does "add an attribute" mean exactly? If you keep/project the x & y attributes of the new Z do you get the old Z? Are there any other restrictions? Does the value for the new attribute in some row depend on what else is in X or Y or the new Z? These details *matter*.

Comment: I mean that:
 For example, If i have in the X table attributes like (xid, xname), and (yid, ytopic), Table Z will have the attributes xid, yid as foreign keys and rate as an attribute (it will have 3 attributes).
now everyone of X can rate anyone of Y.
Is that correct thinking or there is misunderstand?